# Merging files in one folder with files in another repeatedly

Tags: bash, file, loops, directory, repeat

I have mfcc features in one file and f0 in another I want to put them together in one file for all the files in the directory and save it to a file in another directory for each file in mfc

```
paste -d '\t' /home/Documents/mfc/3.mfc.txt /home/Documents/f0/34-114.f0.txt > /home/fs/34-114.txt
```

the command works for one file I want to make it work for all files

I tried

```
for file in /home/Documents/mfc/*; do

    paste -d '\t' $file /home/Documents/f0/$(basename $file ).f0.txt > /home/Documents/fs/$(basename $file ).txt

done
```

which returned error saying files not found as the extensions of files in the f0 folder were different

```
paste: /home/home/Documents/f0/6.raw.f.mfc.txt.f0.txt: No such file or directory
paste: /home/home/Documents/f0/7.raw.f.mfc.txt.f0.txt: No such file or directory
paste: /home/home/Documents/f0/8.raw.f.mfc.txt.f0.txt: No such file or directory
paste: /home/home/Documents/f0/9.raw.f.mfc.txt.f0.txt: No such file or directory
paste: /home/home/Documents/f0/10.raw.f.mfc.txt.f0.txt: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script actually did the trick.
It was the file name and extensions that actually messed up the script I posted in the question.

```
for file in /home/Documents/mfc//*; do

fname=$(basename "$file" .raw.f.mfc.txt)

    paste -d '\t' $file /home/Documents/f0/$fname.f0.txt > /home/Documents/fs/$fname.txt

done
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(/home/Documents/mfc/*txt)
arr2=(/home/Documents/f0/*.txt)
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#arr[@]}-1))); do
    paste -d "\t" ${arr[$i]} ${arr2[$i]}
done
```

This script assumes that you have same number of files in both folders. If you want output to be put in multiple files you need to redirect standard output to some file

E.g.

```
    paste -d "\t" ${arr[$i]} ${arr2[$i]} >> file$i.txt
```